# changing build command for openCV on Android NDK mac OS X

Tags: android, opencv, build, android-ndk

I am using Eclipse Classic 4.2.1 Juno on mac OS X 10.6.8 snow leopard, with Android SDK and NDK installed.

in the following tutorial

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html#o4a-sdk

it says,

"After the initial import, on a non-Windows (Linux and Mac OS) operating system Eclipse will still show build errors for applications with native C++ code. To resolve the issues, please do the following:
Open Project Properties -> C/C++ Build, and replace “Build command” text to "${NDKROOT}/ndk-build" (remove .cmd at the end)."

when I go to Project Properties there is no "C/C++ Build" option in the menu,  how do I change the build command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you install Eclipse CDT, "C/C++ Build" is shown. 
If you already install it, you can find it in Eclipse properties not project properties.

Comment: There is other way to compile C/C++ source code using NDK.
Instead of using "C/C++ Build", you can add a ndk-builder. 
Open project properties->Builders->New->select Program and click OK.
Then, the configuration window is shown. 
In Location, you put the absolute address of ndk-build.
And, in Working directory, you put the address of C/C++ source folder to be compiled.